# UISearchDisplayController with custom cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller, custom-cell

I have a Custom Cell designed in `storyboard`, it is inside a `UITableViewController` which is working fine with the custom cell.

Now, I'm trying to use the same cell on a `UITableViewController` with a `UISearchDisplayController` and it is not working.

This is my method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";

    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier ];
    }

    cell.titleLabel.text = object[@"title"];
    cell.subtitleLabel.text = object[@"subtitle"];

    return cell;
}
```

It just return white, regular cells, and if I use the default `cell.textLabel.text` it shows my objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, set Tag on storybord

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVXPE.jpg

[image from AppCoda](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-customize-uitableview-storyboard/)

And change your method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";

CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier ];
}

//Change this - START

UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
UILabel *subtitleLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];

titleLabel.text = object[@"title"];
subtitleLabel.text = object[@"subtitle"];

//Change this - END

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have made the custom cell inside a tableview on the storyboard I don't know if you can use it in another tableview either remake the custom cell in the new tableView on the story board or make a seperate custom .xib just for the cell and load them in you cellForRow methods with something like..

```
CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if(!cell)
{
    [tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCustomCellNib" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or even better, you could just make a small change in your existing code, and hopefully it will work:

From:

```
CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

To:

```
CustomCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Or in **Swift**

From:

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CellIdentifier) as! CustomCell
```

To:

```
var cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CellIdentifier) as! CustomCell
```

[Credits](http://burfdevelopment.com/uisearchcontroller-and-custom-cells/)